# Show $G$ is not abelian of order 8.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group whose elements are expression in terms of $x,y \in G$ such that 
>   $\lvert \langle x\rangle \rvert =4$, $\lvert \langle y\rangle \rvert=2$, $xy=yx^3$. Show $G$ is not abelian of order 8.

Can anyone give me a hit to start this question ? Thanks

Comment: `<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for that meaning only; to make angle brackets, use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: suppose $yx=xy$, what do you get from this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this geometrically.  This is the dihedral group of order $8$.  It is the group of symmetries of a square.  The element $x$ is rotation by $90^{\circ}$ and $y$ is reflection.  You could show that these two symmetries satisfy the relations you have.  And then you could show that rotating by a certain amount and reflecting is different than reflecting and then rotating by the certain amount by using a square with labeled vertices.

Answer (score 1):

It is not abelian, because if it were,
$$xy=yx=yx^3\implies x^2=1$$
contradicting that the order of $x$ is $4$.

Can you try to enumerate the elements of $G$?

Answer (score 0):

Take the relation and multiply on the left by $y$, so
$$ yxy = y^2 x^3 = ex^3 = x^3. $$
Now suppose $G$ is abelian, so in particular, $xy=yx$, so
$$ x^3 = yxy = y^2 x = ex= x, $$
and multiplying both sides by $x$, you'll find a contradiction.